# Googleスプレッドシートにフォームから追記されたらメールを送信したい

Tags: google-apps-script

WordPress に "Contact Form 7" と "CF7 Google Sheet Connector" を入れ、Contact Form 7からの入力をGoogleスプレッドシートの『シート1』の一番下へと追記するようにしております。

ここで、Contact Form 7のprefの項目へとユーザー様の都道府県を入力頂いて、それを『シート2』
の都道府県vs担当者メアド対応表についてVLOOKUPをつかって検索し、メールを投げたいと思って
おります。
Contact Form 7でadminに送られてきますメールではなく、各都道府県の担当者へ別途指示を出しますメールを作成したいです。

そこで、以下のコードを書きましたが上手く動いてくれません。

Googleフォームを使用しておりませんので、トリガーを

イベントのソースを選択　：　スプレッドシートから
イベントの種類を選択　　：　フォーム送信時

としておりますが、１回も実行されておりません。

また、トリガーと別にデバッグをしますと、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
sendform    @ コード.gs:4
```

'response'のスペルを何度も確認しましたがミスは無さそうで、フラグと合わせてダブルパンチで困っております。

この手のプログラムは初めてで、ネット検索しながらコピペで使用しておりますので、素人を助けてくださいますかたお願いいたします。

---

```
// FormApp.getActiveForm()

function sendform(e) {
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var q = item.getItem().getTitle();
    if ( q === "pref" ) {
      var a = item.getResponse();
      var mail_address = VLOOKUP(a,importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxx-xx--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/","シート2!$A$1:$D$48"),3,FALSE) ;
      var message = VLOOKUP(a,importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxx-xx--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/","シート2!$A$1:$D$48"),4,FALSE) + 'にお住まいのお客様からの依頼です\n\n' ;

      GmailApp.sendEmail(mail_address, 'お問い合わせがありました', message);

    }
  }
}
```

**シート2**

```
  A         B              C            D
北海道　〇〇株式会社　XXX@example.com　北海道(←メッセージは後から変更しますが、取り敢えず都道府県を入れております)
```

Comment: 引数として渡ってくるeをコンソールログ等でデバッグするとなにが渡ってきていますか？

Answer (score 1):

自己レスですが、

```
function sendform(e) {
```

で持ってくることが出来なかったので

```
function sendform() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();

  var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, lastRow ,12);
  var currentRangeValues = range.getValues();
```

として、トリガーを

イベントのソースを選択： スプレッドシートから
イベントの種類を選択　： 変更時

としましてなんとか…